# There is no ConditionalExpression warning for an Indeterminate case in Integers

Tags: simplifying-expressions, conditional

This expression yields `Pi` in the limit `m -> n` in the `Complexes` domain.

But for `{n, m} ∈ Integers`, it should be zero or `Indeterminate`, depending on `n==m`.

However, `Simplify[]` yields zero **for all `Integers`**  `m` and `n`.

```
Simplify[Sin[(m - n) π]/(m - n), m ∈ Integers && n ∈ Integers]
(* 0 *)
```

**Why don't we get a [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)?
Is this a bug or a feature?**

Comment: Mathemaica is right because the expression Sin[Pi*0]/0 is Indeterminate.  A generic result is outputted.

Comment: The output is 0. You would expect a conditional expression, right?

Comment: The result is what is referred to as *[generically correct](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericCases.html)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why don't we get a [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) ?

As  J. M. commented *"The result is what is referred to as generically correct. "*.

The problem is related to the issue discussed in the *Possible Issues* section of the documentation for the [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) function. Some of the transformations `FullSimplify` uses are only generically correct.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Analyzing the conditions

The [`FunctionDomain`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html) has restrictions

```
FunctionDomain[
 Sin[(m - n) π]/(m - n)
 , {n, m}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

so you need to see the case `n==m` independently.

But,

```
Reduce[
 Sin[(m - n) π]/(m - n) == 0
 , {n, m}
 , Integers
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

I guess I have to agree with the OP that one would expect a  [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) for the `Indeterminate` case when `n == m`.

### For `Integers`

Case `n == m`

```
Assuming[
 {n, m} ∈ Integers && n == m,
 Simplify[
  Sin[(m - n) π]/(m - n)
  ]
 ]
```

> Indeterminate

Case `n != m`

```
Assuming[
 {n, m} ∈ Integers && m != n,
 FullSimplify[
  Sin[(m - n) π]/(m - n)
  ]
 ]
```

> 0

### For `Reals`

```
Assuming[
 {n, m} ∈ Reals,
 Limit[
  Sin[(m - n) π]/(m - n)
  , n -> m
  ]
 ]
```

> π

```
Assuming[
 {m, n} ∈ Reals && m != n,
 Simplify@Reduce[
   Sin[(m - n) π]/(m - n) == 0
   , {n, m}
   ]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

You are interested in a limit $m \to n$ and you can convince Mathematica to perform it with

```
Limit[Sin[(m - n) \[Pi]]/(m - n), m -> n]

(* \[Pi] *)
```